# Openshift oc patch not executing initdb.sql from /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

OpenShift:

I have the below MySQL Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-master
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-master
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql-master
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ro-mstr-nfs-datadir-claim
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.7
        name: mysql-master
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_SERVER_CONTAINER
          value: mysql
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: MYSQL_DATABASE
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: MYSQL_USER
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql-master
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
```

I created a deployment using this yml file which created a deployment and pod which is successfully running.

And I have a configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ro-mstr-mysqlinitcnfgmap
data:
  initdb.sql: |-
    CREATE TABLE aadhaar ( name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    sex char NOT NULL, birth DATE  NOT NULL, death DATE  NULL,
    id int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id) );
    CREATE USER 'usera'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'usera';
    GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'usera' IDENTIFIED BY 'usera';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now I need to patch the above deployment using this configmap.  I am using the below command

```
oc patch deployment mysql-master -p '{ "spec": { "template": { "spec": { "volumes": [ { "name": "ro-mysqlinitconf-vol", "configMap": { "name": "ro-mstr-mysqlinitcnfgmap" } } ], "containers": [ { "image": "mysql:5.7", "name": "mysql-master", "volumeMounts": [ { "name": "ro-mysqlinitconf-vol", "mountPath": "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" } ] } ] } } } }'
```

So the above command is successful, I validated the Deployment description and inside the container it placed the initdb.sql file successfully, and recreated the pod. But the issue is it has not created the aadhaar table. I think it has not executed the initdb.sql file from `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

Comment: did you sepcify `MYSQL_DATABASE`? SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable.https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: Thank you for your time, I understood that from the link given by you is the MYSQL_DATABASE is optional, you can specify a name for a database to be created on startup. The above code is working perfectly if I place the patch code in deployment file itself. The code is not working if create deployment first and then patching....

Answer (score 2):

If you dive into the entrypoint script in your image (https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/75f81c8e20e5085422155c48a50d99321212bf6f/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L341-L350) you can see it only runs the initdb.d files if it is also creating the database the first time. I think maybe you assumed it always ran them on startup?

Comment: Thank you very much, very informative, can you please help me in solving this? What I am trying is there will be a MySQL container running in kubernetes/openshift, I need to do two things. 1. Create a table and user for this I have initdb.sql and secondly I need to update my.cnf of MySQL for this I am creating a custom file inside conf.d folder of MySQL contianer. Unfortunately this may not work. Please suggest an approach, I will try.

Comment: Instead of creating the deployment and then patching, just do it all at once and it will work as you expect (assuming you are starting from a blank persistent volume).

Comment: As I mentioned, my use case is that. In prod a container will be running, I need patch it. Please suggest an approach.

Comment: Then you can't use the initdb.d feature, you need to run your SQL against the DB using the mysql command line tool instead.

Comment: But what i am not understanding is oc patch command is destroying the pod and recreating it, so in that case it will be starting a new container - now container has to execute files in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Right?

Comment: No, because you are storing the database files on the persistent volume. It does recreate the pod, but the initdb.d files only matter the very first time it starts when it initializes things.